# Check variables against a dictionary, and print the dictionary contents remaining

Tags: python, dictionary, set, theory

I want to check user inputs against a dictionary, and then print the values that still exist in the dictionary that were not inputed by the user.

Here's my code that takes user input, checks it against the dictionary and sends it to the print function below.

```
    elif choice == '7':
    print("Enter at least 4 pitches")
    set1 = str(input("Enter first pitch: "))
    set2 = str(input("Enter second pitch: "))
    set3 = str(input("Enter third pitch: "))
    set4 = str(input("Enter fourth pitch: "))
    set5 = str(input("Enter fifth pitch or type 'Done': "))
    if set5 == 'Done':
        setset1 = f(set1)
        setset2 = f(set2)
        setset3 = f(set3)
        setset4 = f(set4)

        setc4(setset1, setset2, setset3, setset4)
```

Here's my function that prints what was found in the dictionary and then prints what is left.

```
def setc4(vset1, vset2, vset3, vset4):
print(" ")
print("The complement of the four note set")
print(vset1, vset2, vset3, vset4)
print("is")
```

Basically I need the function to check user input (i.e. A and B) and then print everything else in the dictionary that's not A and B (i.e. C, D and E). Essentially I'm running a 'set' and 'complement' analysis, where the user inputs the set and then the complement of that set is printed.

What's the best way of going about this? Thanks!

Here's my 'notes' dictionary.

```
notes = {
'Bs': 0,
'C': 0,
'Cs': 1,
'Db': 1,
'D': 2,
'Ds': 3,
'Eb': 3,
'E': 4,
'Fb': 4,
'Es': 5,
'F': 5,
'Fs': 6,
'Gb': 6,
'G': 7,
'Gs': 8,
'Ab': 8,
'A': 9,
'As': 10,
'Bb': 11,
'B': 11,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `difference` function to compute set difference.

```
number_of_inputs = ...
inputs = []
dictionary = {...}

def print_diff():
    for i in range(number_of_inputs + 1):
        inputs.append(str(input("enter pitch {}".format(i + 1))))
    if inputs[-1] == 'Done':
        del inputs[-1]
        diff = dictionary.difference(set(inputs))
        print('The complement is ')
        for element in diff:
            print(element)
```

For example:

```
>>> number_of_inputs = 4
>>> dictionary = {'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'}
>>> print_diff()

enter pitch 1
three
enter pitch 2
five
enter pitch 3
one
enter pitch 4
five
enter pitch 5
Done
The complement is
two
four
six
seven
```

Note that the underlying dictionary data structure is not a `dict` but a `set`. This is because you don't really need the keys of your key-value pairs. Since the dictionary you actually have is a `dict` you can drop the keys and convert it to a set as follows:

```
dictionary = set(dictionary.values())
```

According to the edit you've made to your question, there's a mismatch between the types of values in your dictionary and the types of values you get as input from the user. Specifically, you get `str`s, but you have a dictionary of `int`s. You can either convert your dictionary to a set of `str`s or retrieve `int`s from the user.

Converting the dictionary from a set of `int`s to a set of `str`s can be done as follows:

```
dictionary = {str(i) for i in dictionary}
```

(you should execute the above line after the `dictionary = set(dictionary.values())`)

Retrieving `int`s from the user instead of `str`s can be done as follows:

```
int(input("enter pitch {}".format(i + 1)))
```

instead of

```
str(input("enter pitch {}".format(i + 1)))
```

Comment: I've implemented this in, but I've got an 'dict object has no attribute difference' error. What do you suggest? My dictionary is called 'notes' so I've written notes.difference(set(inputs)).

Comment: AlexC: As I understand your problem, your dictionary is actually a set of words, right? It's not a set of key-value pairs. In that case you should use a `set` (not a `dict`) as the underlying data structure. That is, initialize your dictionary as I've done in the example above.

Comment: AlexC: You can convert your dictionary to a set (as all you need is the values, you can drop the keys). See the edit I've made to my answer.

Comment: Great, the function is working and the dictionary has been converted to a set with a new name (note_set). However the complement is being listed as all numbers 0-11 which is not correct. I've posted my notes dictionary in my original post to show you. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: I've converted my dictionary to a list of strings, however it's now printing all the complement numbers as before (0-11) but in a random order. i.e. 0, 10, 5, 4. Is this because I have multiple variables assigned to the same numbers, and it's only checking against the first instance of the number? i.e. Bs = 0 and C = 0, but it's only checking against C so 0 still remains. Thanks for your help so far I really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114035/discussion-between-snakile-and-alexc).

Comment: As for the fact that the order of the output seems arbitrary, this is because sets (as well as dictionaries) are unordered data structures. Therefore, the order of the elements, while not actually random, is not explicitly defined. This can easily be solved by sorting the output (i.e., `sorted(list(diff))`). Note that if you want to sort the list, the values should be `int` s. Otherwise the list is going to be sorted alphabetically.  As for the bug causing the output to consist of the whole dictionary, let's resolve this in chat.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can simply use `dict.pop()`. `pop` returns the value of a specified key, then removes it from the dictionary. It the specified key doesn't exist in the dictionary it will return None by default.

```
a_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

print(a_dict.pop('a'))
>> 1
print(a_dict)
>> {'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Great! However I have some variables that equal the same number, like Bs : 0 and C : 0. The dictionary is still printing the second one. Anyway to remove all of the matching variables, not just the first one? Also how can I print a dictionary with just the variables and not all the { } brackets? Thank you!!